# C++ strcat is ignoring an argument?

Tags: c++, argv, strcat

Newbie here. I'm trying to concat the args of a C++ program into a single char array. For some reason, `strcat` is selectively ignoring `argv[2]` in the for-loop:

```
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *argstr = argv[1];

    for(int i=2; i < argc; i++) {
        argstr = std::strcat(argstr, " ");
        argstr = std::strcat(argstr, argv[i]);
    }

    std::cout << argstr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The file is named `qtimer`. So, the expected output of running:

`qtimer asdf 1 2 3`

would be:

`asdf 1 2 3`

but instead it's outputting:

`asdf  2 3` (with two spaces after `asdf`)

Could anyone explain why this is? Also, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `std::strcat` just looks wrong! You shouldn't be using these rubbish c functions, when you have `std::string`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are appending to the string stored in `argv[1]`, but you don't know that there is space there. You are overwriting memory that does not belong to you.

This is undefined behavior, and anything could happen.

Most likely, the memory you are overwriting is the memory where the other arguments are stored, so that by the time you are accessing them, they are already corrupted.

You should use `std::string` for string operations in C++, it is much better and safer.

Comment: For completeness, I would add that to fix their code they could allocate a sufficiently large space (or calculate exactly how much they would need). For example: `char* argstr = malloc(1024); memset(argstr, 1024, 0);` to prepare 1k space for the result.

Comment: @Sorin Why dynamic allocation? For this purpose you can, just as easily (even more easily, since you don't need to free it afterwards), create an array on the stack `char buffer[1024] = {0}`.

Comment: 1024 is not enough.  You need to loop round calculating the space.

Comment: And this discussion is the reason he should just use `std::string`.